# Регулярное выражение для поиска времени в формате HH:MM:SS.MS

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Дан текст

```
ffmpeg version N-69920-g8bc8001 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enab
le-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavformat    56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.100 /  5. 11.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Downloads\1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2015-09-27 17:21:17
  Duration: 02:34:41.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 374 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 275 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-27 17:21:37
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
```

Нужно найти длительность видео файла в данном случаи она 02:34:41.18 и перевести её в секунды.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй такое выражение:

```
Duration:\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).(\d+)
```

Answer (score 3):

Учим матчасть?

ffmpeg -i не правильно. Он не для того предназначен.

Используем ffprobe. Он входит в состав пакета ffmpeg.

Немного магии

```
# ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams Doctor.Who.s03.e01.Smith.and.Jones.2007.x264.bluray.720p.mkv
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "High",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1001/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "width": 1264,
            "height": 720,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "79:45",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 41,
            "r_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "avg_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "eng"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "ac3",
            "codec_long_name": "ATSC A/52A (AC-3)",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "dmix_mode": "-1",
            "ltrt_cmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "ltrt_surmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "loro_cmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "loro_surmixlev": "-1.000000",
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "bit_rate": "192000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "rus"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "codec_name": "dca",
            "codec_long_name": "DCA (DTS Coherent Acoustics)",
            "profile": "DTS",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 6,
            "channel_layout": "5.1(side)",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "bit_rate": "1536000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "eng"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 3,
            "codec_name": "subrip",
            "codec_long_name": "SubRip subtitle",
            "codec_type": "subtitle",
            "codec_time_base": "1/1000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 2800757,
            "duration": "2800.757000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "rus"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 4,
            "codec_name": "subrip",
            "codec_long_name": "SubRip subtitle",
            "codec_type": "subtitle",
            "codec_time_base": "1/1000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 2800757,
            "duration": "2800.757000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "eng"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "Doctor.Who.s03.e01.Smith.and.Jones.2007.x264.bluray.720p.mkv",
        "nb_streams": 5,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "matroska,webm",
        "format_long_name": "Matroska / WebM",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "2800.757000",
        "size": "2411666588",
        "bit_rate": "6888613",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "encoder": "libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1",
            "creation_time": "2014-03-12 11:41:12"
        }
    }
}
```